# ASP.NET javascript debugging does not work in 2 projects

Tags: asp.net, javascript, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have 2 asp.net web applications, one of which is the main application and the second one is referencing the first application for like master pages , themes etc, and the main frameset that will point to the second application's webform based on database values (menu generated from database);

All my actual forms are in the second application, but the problem is when I set a breakpoint on the javascript file on my second application, it doesnt go into the breakpoint?

Any advice please?  I need to get the debugger working, without having the need to put in the "debugger" keyword in javascript if possible.

My IDE is visual studio 2008 SP 1 and IE 8 as the browser.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the solution set up to start up both projects with debugging when you start the debugger?  To set multiple startup projects, right-click on the solution.  Choose Set Startup Projects.  In the dialog, select multiple startup projects and set the two web sites to start up with debugging when the debugger is started.

For what it's worth, I usually like to debug my javascript in Firefox with Firebug.  I much prefer that to the developer tools in IE 8.